# функцию, которая загрузит текстовый файл и ее результатом будет словарь

Tags: python, функции, словарь

Нужно разработать функцию, которая загрузит текстовый файл и ее результатом будет словарь, содержащий все слова и числа фигурирующие в тексте с указанием количества их появлений. Слова они состоят из букв английского алфавита (верхнего и нижнего регистра) и могут быть разделены не только пробелами, но и другими небуквенными символами. Буквы не чувствительны к регистру(«Аnnа», «АNNА», - одно и то же слово). Числа состоят из цифр, которым может предшествовать знак минус ('-') и могут содержать десятичную точку. Параметры вызова функции должны быть: имя (вместе с путем) файл и кодовую таблицу, которая использовалась для сохранения файла.  Результатом функции для файла с текстом “Anna, ANNA, 45.65, 77d54, 77, 5,6” , будет: {‘anna’:2, 45:1, 65:1, 77:2, ‘d’:1, 54:1, 5,6:1}

Вот код который я написала, объясните, пожалуйста, где ошибка и почему он не работает

```
 def wlicznik(nazwa_pliku,kodowanie='utf-16'):
     with open(nazwa_pliku,'r',encoding=kodowanie) as f: 
         tekst = f.readlines() 
         print (tekst) 
         Dict = {} 
         for line in tekst: 
             for i in range(len(line)): 
                 if line[i].isdigit(): 
                 import re 
                 from re import split 
                 a = split(r"(([-])?[0-9]+([,]{1}[0-9]+)?)", line) 
                 for n in a: float(n[0].replace(",",".") 
                                   c = n.count
                 for n in a: 
                     if a not in Dict_n(): 
                         Dict_n= {n:c}
                     else: 
                         Dict_n[a]= Dict_n[a]+ 1
 
           elif line[i].isalpha():
           import re
           text_words = re.split(r'[^A-Za-z]', f.read())
           for word in text_words:
              if word:
                   if word.lower() in Dict:
                         Dict_w[word.lower()] += 1
                   else:
                         Dict_w.update({word.lower():1})
        Dict.update(Dict_n+Dict_w)
        return Dict 
     f.close()***
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Восстановить Ваш код сложновато отступы как повезет и ошибок много.

По описанию написал функцию с начала. Получается примерно так:

```py
import re

def wlicznik(nazwa_pliku,kodowanie='utf-8'):
    with open(nazwa_pliku, mode="r", encoding=kodowanie) as wf:
        i = wf.read().lower() # Переводим все в нижний регистр
        # Обрабатываем строку без цифр
        no_digit = re.sub(r'[^\w\s\,]+|[\d]+|[\ ,]', r' ',i) # 
        no_digit = re.split(' |\n', no_digit)
        no_digit = [value for value in no_digit if value != '']
        # Обрабатываем строку без букв 
        digit = re.sub(r'[^\d\.\,]+|\,\s', r' ',i)
        digit = digit.replace(",", ".")
        digit = re.split(' |\n', digit)
        digit = [value for value in digit if value != '']
        digit = [value for value in digit if value != ',']

        itog = (no_digit + digit)

# Подсчитываем значения
    arr = {}.fromkeys(itog, 0) # преобразование в словарь
    for a in itog:
        arr[a] += 1
    print(arr)

# Ну и собственно вызов функции
wlicznik("test.txt", "utf-8")
```

Подходит?

Comment: Не до конца
у Вас  этот ответ выглядит так
{'anna': 2, '': 2, '45.65': 1, '77d54': 1, '77': 1, '5,6': 1}
a нужно еще разделить числа.
 В файле могут быть числа разделённые буквами и нужно числа отделить от букв. Еще нужно заменить запятую на точку в числах. Например если в файле будет( 56а45, 45, 5,6  78.70) то на выходе должен выйти словарь{56:1, 45:2, ‘a’:1,  5.6:1, 78:1,  70:1}

Comment: Поправил пример

Comment: Спасибо большое, Вы мне очень помогли

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать без регулярок за один проход:

- перебираем строку, проверяя каждый символ.
- если символ подходящий (цифра, буква) и соответствует предыдущему, кладём его в аккумулятор. Запятую обрабатываем отдельно, она может быть как частью, так концом последовательности.
- если символ неподходящий или не соответствует предыдущему - очередная последовательность закончилась, добавляем содержимое аккумулятора (если он не пустой) в словарь, обнуляем аккумулятор и начинаем наполнять заново.

**Решение:**

Предполагается, что после запятой всегда идёт пробел или цифра.

```
def convert_to_dict(string, dct):
    def add_to_dict():
        nonlocal accum

        accum = accum.lower()
        dct.setdefault(accum, 0)
        dct[accum] += 1 
        accum = ""

    accum = ""
    string_iterator = iter(string)  

    for char in string_iterator:
        #  Если это алфавитный или числовой символ - короткая версия
        if char.isalnum():
            if accum != "" and accum[-1].isalpha() != char.isalpha():
                add_to_dict()

            accum += char
#  Если это алфавитный или числовой символ - длинная, но более понятная версия
#       if char.isalpha():
#           if accum != "" and not accum[-1].isalpha():
#               add_to_dict()
#
#           accum += char
#
#       elif char.isdigit():
#           if accum != "" and not accum[-1].isdigit():
#               add_to_dict()
#
#           accum += char

        else:
            if char == ',':
                next_char = next(string_iterator)

                if next_char.isdigit():
                    accum += '.' + next_char
                    continue

            add_to_dict()
    # Проверяем, не осталось ли что-нибудь в аккумуляторе.
    if accum != "":
        add_to_dict()

with open("input.txt") as fd:
    result_dct = {}
    #  Можно читать файл построчно, передавая каждую строку отдельно
    for line in fd:
        convert_to_dict(line, result_dct)
#  А можно передать сразу весь файл
#   convert_to_dict(fd.read(), result_dct)

    print(result_dct)
```

**Тестирование**

Содержимое файла `input.txt`:

```
Anna, ANNA, 45.65, 77d54, 77, 5,6
56a45, 45, 5,6, 78.70
```

**Результат**

```
{'anna': 2, '45': 3, '65': 1, '77': 2, 'd': 1, '54': 1, '5.6': 2, '56': 1, 'a': 1, '78': 1, '70': 1}
```